# In David Brin's "Kiln People," why is Ritu's head shaved?

Tags: character-motivation, david-brin, kiln-people

In David Brin's novel *Kiln People,* there is an unclear reference--once--to Ritu having a shaved head, but no explanation as to when or why or how this happened.

> Did Beta, her criminal alter ego, make her do it so he/she could more easily control a bunch of giant war-golems?

This is mentioned at the point where Albert Morris has a strange, transcendent experience at the climax of the novel.

> "First, look around for Ritu. An earlier version of that
>  wounded-confused soul. You'll detect her soon, filled with
>  self-loathing as she surrenders to an inner craving beyond her
>  self-control, laying her shaved head between the poles of a
>  high-capacity tetragrammatron while autokilns warm up nearby,
>  preparing several dozen giant golems built for war."

Comment: Note: I had a lot of difficulty/technical problems with the formatting of this question, otherwise I would have spoiler-texted the paragraph I posted. I did rewrite the middle sentence to make it less spoilery.

Comment: I've spoiler texted it for you. Markdown on SE is somewhere between infuriating and straight-up incomprehensible.

Answer (score 1):

## It's left over from an earlier disguise.

Earlier in the novel, Ritu needed to send a ditto of herself on a trip for which travelling in her original body would have been suspicious.  Being unable to transfer her original personality into a golem body, she shaved her head so that she could disguise herself as a copy.